# What are the benefits of converting data using a scalar-valued function as opposed to doing the conversion directly in your code?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the code being used:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ConvertInttoString]
(@inValue int)
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
-- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
RETURN (convert(varchar(1000),@inValue));
END
```

GO

It is being used to do a data conversion on an integer input as a part of Dynamic SQL:

```
 IF (@strValue IS NULL) OR (RTRIM(LTRIM(@strValue)) = '')
BEGIN
SET @strSQL = 'UPDATE ' + @strTableName + 'SET ' +                       @strColumnName  + ' = NULL ' + 
                            ' WHERE ' +  @strColumnPrimaryKey + ' = ' + dbo.fn_ConvertInttoString(@intPrimaryID) + ';'
        SET @strOutputMessage = 'SUCCESS! ' + @strTableName + ' Updated!';
    END
```

What is the benefit of doing the conversion this way?

Thanks,

Taylor

Comment: None. There are quite a few issues with that code. Should use `QUOTENAME`. No need for UDF anyway but if there is one it should use `SCHEMABINDING` and have a sensible return type. An `int` will never need `varchar(1000)`. The whole need for this code/approach is questionable.

Comment: Scalar functions are notoriously poor performers. Your code not only have scalar functions it is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: This is code that I am looking into and it all looks wrong, so I am glad you guys are confirming that.

Comment: Why @intPrimaryID needs to be converted to varchar? Is the primary key varchar or int? Also. What is the point of such a universal sql dynamic code that just updates a column to null and is plenty of security holes?

Comment: This code was written four years ago by a .net guy to be used as an all-encompassing insert and update procedure for every single table in this particular database.  I have never even seen anybody try to do an update like this so I was wondering if there was any benefit in keeping it as it is.  It seems that everybody is in agreement to code this in such a way that doesn't use SQL injection.

Comment: If you are using c# as the language to build the client app, I would suggest you to use an ORM like EntityLite. To do what the code does, in EntityLite your write: myEntity.MyField = null; MyEntityRepository.Update(myEntity, MyEntityFields.MyField);. No SQL injection, no scalar valued funcion, and no conversions.

Comment: No there is no benefit to keeping this code but there is a lot of benefit in replacing it with something that is useful. A single procedure to handle inserts into any table is kind of like creating a method in .net that can do something for all object types. Creating the "One Procedure to Rule Them All" is something that comes up from time to time and is always horrible for performance, maintenance and debugging.

Comment: I just talked to my team about breaking apart our one procedure into individual ones.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: "This code was written four years ago by a .net guy to be used as an all-encompassing insert and update procedure for every single table in this particular database". Oh God, not again.